# canada visitor visa expiry for minor accompanying parents

Tags: visas

My child's visitor visa expires in 4 days after I enter Canada from India but our return tickets is after 1 month. What is the extra procedure I have to follow to make sure our trip is good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. You are already good.

Similar to US visas, Canada visas' expiration dates indicate the last date which you may *enter* the country. They have no bearing on how long you can stay in the country.

However, your *passport* expiration date is important. You must depart Canada on or before the expiration date of the passport.